# Iframes containing phps files are automatically downloaded

Tags: iframe, download

I really don't understand this, I created several tutorials that contain iframes with phps files(examples of code). On my localhost server they were displayed fine, now that I've uploaded it to my webhost it starts downloading the iframes sources when I open the tutorials.

What can be the cause of this??

Comment: Are they downloaded as pure code or as interpreted PHP output? Take a look at your server preferences. Perhaps it just a wrong file type extension (some servers will only handle `.php` as PHP executable code, not `.php5` or `.html` e.g.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No, the files actually contain the source, it's not interpreted.

Comment: I've added the following line to my htaccess file:
AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
Still no luck...